# Facebook SDK - Posting from the android app to Facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

I need to post something from my Android app to the FB's wall. I checked some tutorials online but they are really old... And I also checked the one on facebook developer site but it uses the MainFragment class and so on (I did not use the facebook login button, I made my own one).
 Can someone gimme some tips for this "publishing on wall?" Thank you very much guys :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout Parse SDK for Android
https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-android